# Connection Java to sqlite (Netbeans)

Tags: java, sqlite, netbeans, connection

I'm having a problem, not sure how to fix:

connection code:

```
public class sqliteConnection {
    Connection conn = null;

    public static Connection dbConnector() {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:V:\\Database\\table.sqlite");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Conected to Database");
            return conn;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

and where I'm using this connection:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    try{
        String sql="insert into test (test) value (?)";
        PreparedStatement pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, Test.getText());    
    }catch (Exception e){
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I'm getting a `SQLITE_ERROR SQL error or missing database (near "value": syntax error)` error, and I cant tell where the error could come from. I just created a test table in `sqlite` to test the connection, with one column which is a 'TEXT' named test. any help?

Comment: `VALUES` not `VALUE`.

Comment: Since this was just a typo I would recommend deleting this question.